What's the difference between "business is booming" vs "business is a-booming"
This is a line from "Inglourious Basterds" by Quentin Tarantino.
"We in the killing Nazi business, and , cousin , business is a-booming."

Is there any difference between "business is booming" vs "business is a-booming"?

What is this type of phraseology called?
I'm pretty sure I've heard it on "many an occasion" (which by the by is similar to these kinds of linguisting hijinks).


P.S "Time's a-wasting" also came to mind.

Originally, such forms were essentially dialectal. A few survive as "fossilized forms" in mainstream English, but even they (and certainly modern reprises such as quoted above) are effectively "quaint folksy affectations" today. Best avoided unless you know what you're doing.

Related: What does a the prefix "a-" mean in "a-changing" Also What is the history of adding the a- prefix to form words? and Is there a word category for a certain kind of words beginning with 'a-'? on ELU.

Prefacing a gerund form verb with 'a-' is colloquial, dialect or informal. It is obsolete in modern standard English. Often, obsolete forms survive, fossilised, as fixed expressions, like time's a-wasting.

True, but we still say Time's a-wasting.
